# Is it possible to symbolically reference a Perl core module?

Tags: perl, function, symbolic-references, perl-core

I know I could easily do something like

```
sub sin {
    sin($_[0]);
}
```

and symbolically reference that for every function I need to symb ref, but I'd just like to know if there's a way to do something like

```
{$foo}(123);
```

vs.

```
&{$foo}(123);
```

which works, but not for core functions.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing so? Perhaps there's more than one way to do it.

Comment: Any why use symbolic references, which require the disabling of `use strict`? Why not work with code references instead symbolic references? To reiterate daxim's question, what is your larger goal?

Comment: No real goal, I just want to know if it's possible. My view on symbolic references is that people discourage them because:

a) They're dangerous (strict disallows them).
b) They can only be used on non-lexically-scoped variables.
c) You should just use hashes instead.
d) They're not proper references.

All four points don't really apply to subroutines. Subs are already globally scoped and don't have reference counts (they don't, do they?). In most cases, using symb refs for calling subs can make your code simpler and easier to maintain than if($foo eq "attack") { &attack } elsif( etc etc.

Comment: The implication is that you're taking a string and using it as a subref. If you set that string to "attack" manually, then it's just as easy to set it to \&attack. If you're getting it from the user somehow, then you've got a security risk. In either case, you have to be completely sure of how that string was set, and that it is safe, before using it as a symbolic reference.

Comment: The reason use strict bans symbolic references to subs by default is because you might accidentally dereference a string when you meant to deref a coderef, and accidentally execute some arbitrary code.

Comment: @Blaise In addition, symbolic refs are a security hole as the string could have come from, or be influenced by, user input. This is common in CGI code that uses symbolic refs as a dispatch table. They also make your code more difficult to puzzle out. You can no longer see where each subroutine or global variable is used. Each use of a symbolic reference could touch anywhere in the code. The answer is STILL to use a hash to control and restrict the possibilities.  `$dispatch{attack} = \&attack;  $dispatch{$foo}->();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK no, you can't do it.  For performance reasons, `CORE` functions never look at the symbol table UNLESS an equivalent `CORE::GLOBAL` function has been declared at compile time.  Unfortunately, you have to write that `CORE::GLOBAL` function and get it just right to simulate the calling conventions of the real function.  Some `CORE` functions cannot be entirely reproduced without massive hacks, `print` and `open` for example.  Since `CORE::GLOBAL` is global an effects all your code and all library code you have to be sure to get it *exactly* right or cause very hard to debug errors.  Some modules, such as [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autodie), have to go to great lengths to wrap around core functions.

But here, let me show you where the gun locker and ammo are...

```
my @return = eval "$function(\@args)";
```

...of course, this is a massive security and maintainability hole.  Don't do it.

Comment: I hope the acceptance of this answer doesn't mean you're actually going to use it.

Comment: It's the answer I wanted, that's all. In any ordinary program I wouldn't use the eval thing you suggested.. But these are extraordinary times... It's just a calculator script ( while(1){our $ans = eval <STDIN>; say $ans } ) I made in a minute for myself, with a few AUTOLOADed functions like asin, acos, etc. I just wanted the least typing to make these functions, and the eval does the job.

Answer (score 2):

If I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585560/can-you-take-a-reference-of-a-builtin-function-in-perl) correctly, you cannot take a reference to a built-in function. I suspect that analogous difficulties will prevent you from invoking built-ins using symbolic references.

Regarding the use of symbolic references to invoke code, I would suggest that you use a dispatch table instead. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub sin_deg { sin $_[0] * atan2(1, 1) / 45 }

my %dt = (
    sin_deg => \&sin_deg,
    attack  => sub { print "Attacking: @_\n" },
);

print $dt{sin_deg}->(60), "\n";

$dt{attack}->(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to override the core functions at compile time, and then you can fiddle with them. I like the dispatch hash (or scalar) approach better, though.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $s;
BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::sin= sub { sin($_[0])*2 };
  *CORE::GLOBAL::cos= sub { cos($_[0])*2 };
  our $s= *CORE::GLOBAL::sin;
}

*CORE::GLOBAL::sin= *CORE::GLOBAL::cos;
print sin(0.01)."\n";
print $s->(0.01)."\n";
```