# Perl built in functions as a subroutine reference

Tags: perl

I am trying to a set of operations to be performed as an array. For this, I have to pass sub routine references. (There may be other ways to perform this without using an array. But, I feel this is best for now, due to certain other constraints).

Basic sample code for what I am trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
sub test()
{
   print "Tested\n";
}

my $test;
my  @temp = (1, 2, 3);
my $operations = [ 
           [\&test, undef, undef],
           [\&shift, \$test, \@temp], 
           ];

foreach(@$operations){
   my $func = shift $_;
   my $out = shift $_;
   $$out = $func->(@$_);
}

print Dumper $test;
```

Output observed is:

```
Tested
Undefined subroutine &main::shift called at temp2.pl line 22.
```

Query - Is it possible to pass built in sub routines as a reference?

There are earlier queries already, reg built in functions as a sub routine reference in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585560/can-you-take-a-reference-of-a-builtin-function-in-perl).

As the question was asked about 3 years ealier, was wondering if there is any alternative for it now.
Would appreciate if some one explains why there is a distinction between built in functions and user defined sub routines in this scenario?

Comment: Looks like you mean `$$out = $func->($_)`

Comment: thanks ysth... updated accordingly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shift` isn't a sub; it's an operator just like `and` and `+`. You'll need to create a sub if you want a reference to a sub.

```
[sub { shift(@{$_[0]}) }, \$test, \@temp],
```

---

Related:

- [What are Perl built-in operators/functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7167599/589924)
- [How to get a reference to `print`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69226416/589924)

Comment: shift is listed as as a function in perl help. Is there any difference between function and sub routine. Was assuming  both refer to the same thing.

Comment: @Sid, Opening line of perlfunc: "The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators."

Comment: Just for reference - ikegami's extended answer for ths at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167599/what-are-perl-built-in-operators-functions/7167873#7167873

Comment: How do I know if this answer also true for `sin` and `cos` in `Math::Trig`? I mean, can I use something like `$r = \&sin; $y = $r->( 1 );`? It seems not, but are they operators, too?

Comment: @Bernhard Bodenstorfer, Math::Trig exports some subs with the same name as functions.