# How to reference print in Perl?

Tags: perl

How to reference `print`?

I tried:

```
my $p = \&print;
```

But it throws:

> Undefined subroutine `&main::print`

Comment: `perl -E 'my  $p = sub {print @_}; $p->("Hello\n")'`

Comment: Passing around, modifying and calling.

Comment: You can't take the reference of `print` (see [perldoc CORE](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html)). And feel free to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1585560/4990392) related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be `\&CORE::print`, but [`perldoc CORE` lists `print` as not available](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html#DESCRIPTION).

You can just wrap an anon sub around it and forward the args though:

```
my $p = sub { print @_ };
$p->("hi");
```

Also, the original method sans the backslash works fine in [Perl 6](https://perl6.org/):

```
my $p = &print; $p("hi")
```

Comment: Re "*lists print as not available*", One can only obtain a reference to operators that can be replicated by subroutines, so you can't get a reference to the `print` operator (because of its optional  leading block/glob) any more than you can get a reference to the addition operator (because it's an infix operator).

Comment: Which also works in Perl 6 as-is: `my &add = &infix:<+>; say add 2, 5'; # OUTPUT: 7` 

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with that, but it's likely to cause confusion. At least, the bit in your answer is.